# android development - connecting to a mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

Im trying to connect to a mysql database which is on localhost. i get the error:

**Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused**

The code is:

```
package com.test.poll;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Poll extends Activity {
    InputStream is;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1990"));


        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                                ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                                ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                                ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                        );
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a php script to connect to the database but the app isn't getting that far. Is the url string right? I have seen to use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost....but its not working for me...

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/4779992#4779992